# I have 2 textboxes with random number in them. How can I prevent duplicates with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 textboxes with a random number in each one.  How can I prevent duplicates from being picked.   I thought an if statement would work but don't know how to return to the line that choose the random numbers.  Seriously puzzled.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.txtDate.Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
 Columns("H:K").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "# ??/??"
Range("A1").Select
Me.txtId.SetFocus

txtRand1 = Evaluate("randbetween(1,52)")
txtRand2 = Evaluate("randbetween(1,52)")

If txtRand1 = txtRand2 Then


 End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Nearly there - think about (in words not code!) what you want to do if both numbers are equal.  There are a couple of options, depending on how worried you are about bias etc.

Answer (score 2):

Restate it, simply. But in a loop, so if you're really unlucky and it's the same again, it does it until they are not equal anymore:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Me.txtDate.Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
     Columns("H:K").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "# ??/??"
    Range("A1").Select
    Me.txtId.SetFocus

    txtRand1 = Evaluate("randbetween(1,52)")
    txtRand2 = Evaluate("randbetween(1,52)")

    Do until txtRand1 <> txtRand2
        txtRand2 = Evaluate("randbetween(1,52)")
    Loop

end sub
```

Comment: Well I feel sheepish.  Duh, how simple.  I need to learn not to over think it.  Thanks a million.

Comment: I think you can avoid one extra line of code if you do `Loop until txtRand1 <> txtRand2`.

Comment: @floatpilot99 If I answered you well it would be nice of you to accept the answer :)